# Must the intersection of connected sets be connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness

Must the intersection of two connected sets be connected?

I believe the answer is no, but I am not entirely sure. I think a counter example would be a set that intersects another set in more than one area, yet those intersections are disjoint. (Think of a cylinder that extends through one end of a donut, the hole in the middle, and then the other end of the donut).

Comment: Think of two horseshoe-shaped regions.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnicoherentSpace.html $\;$

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. Consider the intersection of the line segment and the circle in $\varnothing$.

Comment: To me, $\not \exists$ a better answer. +1..

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: how can you come up with this counter examples so quick!

Comment: @ILoveMath: Practice and experience, mostly.